# Linux's equivalent of Windows' timeout command?

Tags: linux, bash, timeout

In windows, there was the `timeout` command, it did something like: `Press any key to continue in 5...` and start counting down. If you killed the process you could cancel, but it gave you a little room to make sure you want to continue but allows automation.

I'm writing a script, and at the end of it it reboots the server. I want to do a 5 second timeout: `Rebooting in 5 sec...`, but allow the user to cancel if they want to do something else before rebooting.

Is there some built-in way/command to do this in bash or do I need to write my own version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is a timeout function but I think what you need can be replicated with `read`

```
read -t 10 -p "press any key to continue: " || true
```